# HTML5 autoplay once

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

The following javascript function serves and autoplays a audio file (via a HTML 5 audio tag), cuts the mp3 playback at 6 seconds and loops + autoplays the audio from the beginning.

javascript:

```
function updateaudio() {    
var a_str = '<audio autoplay source src="audio/coolsound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
document.getElementById('audio_span').innerHTML = a_str;
}
setInterval(updateaudio, 6000)
```

html:

```
<div><span id="audio_span"></span><script src="js/audio.js"></script></div>
```

Is there any using the html5 audio attribute to set autoplay playback to once off i.e. non-looping? Alternatively, is there another way to achieve this (via either javascript or html5)? Upon the audio event ending, I would like to set a flag and stop any playback.

Comment: setTimeout() is the non-looping version of setInterval(), so try that

Comment: Awesome, swapping out setInterval for setTimeout does not pause the playback after 6 seconds, but rather allows the mp3 to play once then halts.

Comment: Is there a necessity for waiting 6 seconds?

Comment: Not necessary at all, setting it to 1 second is fine since I achieve the result in needed (i.e. playing back the mp3 once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use setInterval() if you don't want a loop.

If you simply want to pause the playback after six seconds do:

```
setTimeout( function () {

    document.getElementById('audio_span').pause();

}, 6000)):
```

Comment: audio_span is not the audio tag here. It will throw an error. you need to get `audio` element using `document.getElementById('audio_span').childNodes[0].pause();` Also remove extra paren at the end. Add semicolon instead of colon.